# Can I go from 11.04 to 12.10 in 1 step?

Tags: upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I skip over releases?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases)

I'm at a 11.04 and want to get to 12.10. update-manager only offers me 11.10. Do I have to do 3 separate upgrades to get to 12.10?

Comment: It's not recommended to do that as Upgrading twice or thrice can cause problems. Programs become outdated and/or are incompatible with the new version so they either crash constantly or screw other things up and cause them to crash constantly. I recommend doing a clean install, but if you have the HardDisk space you can make a separate partition for 12.10. This way you can boot to either versions and slowly migrate yourself to the new version until you're ready to switch completely. This is what I did when I switched from 11.04 to 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [it's possible](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1858960), but warned against. For example, the user in my first link began to have issues.

From the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes):

> To avoid damaging your running system, upgrading should only be done
>   from one release to the next release (e.g. Ubuntu 9.04 to Ubuntu 9.10)
>   or from one LTS release to the next (e.g. Ubuntu 6.06 LTS to Ubuntu
>   8.04 LTS). If you wish to 'skip' a version, you can backup your data and do a fresh installation, or progressively upgrade to each
>   successive version. For example, to upgrade from Ubuntu 8.10 to Ubuntu
>   9.10, first upgrade to 9.04, then upgrade 9.04 to 9.10.

However, it does seem that LiveUSBs can upgrade multiple versions?

Discussed in: [upgrade from 10.10 to 11.10](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1859050&page=2)